# Strict inequality in Fatou's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Put $f_n={1}_E$ if $n$ is odd, $f_n=1-1_E$ if $n$ is even. What is the relevance of this example to Fatou's lemma?

**Proof:** We see that $\int \limits_{X}f_nd\mu= \mu(E^c)$ if $n$ is even and $\int \limits_{X}f_nd\mu= \mu(E)$ if $n$ is odd.

It's easy to check that $\liminf \limits_{n\to \infty} f_nd\mu=0$ hence $\int \limits_{X}\liminf \limits_{n\to \infty} f_nd\mu=0$. But $\liminf \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{X} f_nd\mu=\min \{\mu(E^c), \mu(E)\}$ and Fatou's lemma states that $$\int \limits_{X}\liminf \limits_{n\to \infty} f_nd\mu\leqslant \liminf \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{X} f_nd\mu.$$ In our case it's equivalent to $0\leqslant \min\{\mu(E), \mu(E^c)\}$.

But if we consider $X=\mathbb{N}, \mathfrak{M}=2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mu$ be counting measure. Taking $E=\{1\}$ we see that it's measurable and $E^c=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$. In this case $\mu(E)=1$ and $\mu(E^c)=+\infty$ and we get the following strict inequality: $$0< \min\{\mu(E), \mu(E^c)\}=1.$$

Sorry if this topic is repeated. But I would like to know is my proof correct?
Would be very grateful for any suggestions and remarks!

Comment: Looks okay to me...

Comment: @saz, Thanks for checking!