# How to find $\mu(X\setminus A)?$

Tags: measure-theory

This question is  highly motivated from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822271/strict-inequality-in-fatous-lemma)

I was  searching the example .After that this example given below came in my mind

Given that $f_n :X \to [0,\infty]$ is measurable for each positive integer  $n$

let $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$ where  $A=[n,n+1]$

now $\int_{X}\chi_A d\mu=\mu(A)=n+1-n=1$.Then $\int_X{\chi_{X\setminus A}}=\mu(X\setminus A)=?$

My question is that

How to find $\mu(X\setminus A)?$

Comment: If your $X$ is the real line then $\infty=\mu (X\setminus A)+\mu (A) =\mu(X\setminus A)+1$.

Comment: oks that mean $\mu(X)= \mu(A) +\mu(X\setminus A)$ ? Am i right? @Kavi sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ supposed to be $\mathbb{R}$

since  $A \subseteq X$, So $X$ is the disjoint union of $A$ and $X \setminus A$. Hence,
$\mu(X) = \mu(A) + \mu(X\setminus A)$.

$\mu(X\setminus A)=\mu(X) - \mu(A)=\infty-1=\infty$